# OpenCV filtering part of an image

Tags: opencv

I'm using the C++ openCV api, and I would like to selectively blur only certain pixels in an image. What is the best way to do this? I was attempting to do it via submatrices, but haven't been able to get it to work.

```
//5 is the 'radius' i'm blurring (~1/2 kernel width)
cv::Rect srcRect;
srcRect.x = x - 5;
srcRect.y = y - 5;
srcRect.width = 2*5 + 1;
srcRect.height = 2*5 + 1;

cv::Rect dstRect;
dstRect.x = x;
dstRect.y = y;
dstRect.width = 1;
dstRect.height = 1;

cv::Mat src = srcImage(srcRect);
cv::Mat dst = dstImage(dstRect);

cv::blur(src, dst, cv::Size(5,5));
```

With the above code, nothing changes.

When i set both of the rectangles to srcRect, the sub images are blurred, but the entire dst is blurred then, instead of just the single pixel.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

`src` and `dst` must be the same size. In your example, dst is a subregion of exactly one pixel.

Your code is correct, besides the way you build rectangles.

```
Rect srcDstRect(7, 7, 100, 100);
cv::Mat src = srcImage(srcDstRect);
cv::Mat dst = dstImage(srcDstRect);

cv::blur(src, dst, cv::Size(5,5));
```

Comment: It seems that cv::blur blurs _all_ pixels in src. I basically want to modify a single pixel and set it's value to the average of all the values around it. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you have to implement your own blurring, because OpenCV has a builtin border interpolation method. Or make dst a separate image, as big as src, keep src as you defined it, and copy the center of the dst in the orig dstImage

Comment: Actually, in your code, cv::blur creates a new dst matrix, discarding the one you set, because it's not the same size as src. All you have to do is to copy the center pixel back into dstImage.

Answer (score 0):

The input is the original image and blur is the clone image of input

```
int x1=1,y1=1,x2=200,y2=200;

Rect region(x1, y1, x2, y2);

GaussianBlur(input(region), blur(region), Size(5, 5), x,0);
```