# c++ OpenCV How to apply filter to sub rect of Mat?

Tags: c++, opencv

This question is similar, but never was answered: [OpenCV filtering part of an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9985880/opencv-filtering-part-of-an-image)

I'm using opencv2 and c++. I have a Mat, say 300x200, and I want to blur *only* the area in the rectangle with top-left = 50,50 size=100,50. I've been wading through the example and docs on opencv.org, but I cannot determine how to filter, or perform other operations on only a sub-rect from a Mat.

Code in question is below, where `surf` is an SDL_Surface and `rect` is an SDL_Rect (int x,y,w,h). The line with the creation of `Mat src_mat` from the surface is fine as it works well elsewhere. This compiles, but gives the following error.

```
{ // Extra scoping used for the surface_lock.
    using namespace cv;
    surface_lock surf_lock(surf);

    //int rows, int cols, int type, void* data, size_t step=AUTO_STEP
    Mat src_mat = Mat(surf->h, surf->w, CV_8UC4, src->pixels, Mat::AUTO_STEP);
    Mat cropmat(src_mat, Rect(rect.y, rect.y + rect.h, rect.x, rect.x + rect.w));

    blur(crop_mat, crop_mat, Size((depth + 1), (depth + 1)), Point(-1,-1));
}
```

error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x + roi.width <= m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.rows) in Mat, file /build/opencv/src/opencv-2.4.6.1/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 323
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /build/opencv/src/opencv-2.4.6.1/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:323: error: (-215) 0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x + roi.width <= m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.rows in function Mat
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a subrect is a Mat, too.

```
Mat larger; 
Mat roi(larger, Rect(50,50,100,50));

// apply whatever algo on 'roi'
blur( roi,roi, cv::Size(5,5) );
```

Comment: I just got a nifty segfault, so I'm posting the code since I obviously misunderstood your advice.

Comment: answering your edit: your Rect looks terribly broken: Rect(rect.y, rect.y + rect.h, rect.x, rect.x + rect.w); // try plain 'rect' here instead

Comment: cv::Rect is (x,y,w,h), so no y+h, x+w, and you got y and x in reverse

Comment: Updated question, rect is an SDL_Rect, not a cv::Rect.

Comment: ahh, That resolves the exception. However, my SDL_Surface surf is not getting updated. I;ll try to debug myself before further polluting this question. Thanks.