# Assertion error in Grabcut

Tags: android, opencv

I am trying to implement Grabcut in Android from [reference code](http://semaster.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/BgChanger/src/com/opencv/grabcut/android/Grabcut.java). But when I run the code the following error is generated.

Error:

`OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x + roi.width <= m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.rows) in cv::Mat::Mat(const cv::Mat&, const Rect&), file /home/reports/ci/slave_desktop/50-SDK/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 323`

I have also read [Similar article on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19667555/c-opencv-how-to-apply-filter-to-sub-rect-of-mat) and made following changes in the code but still got the same error.

Changed Part of reference code:

```
private void backgroundSubtracting(Mat img, Mat background) {
    Mat firstMask = new Mat();
    Mat bgModel = new Mat();
    Mat fgModel = new Mat();
    Mat mask;
    Mat source = new Mat(1, 1, CvType.CV_8U, new Scalar(3.0));
    dst = new Mat();
    Rect rect = new Rect(318,100,513,349);  // <= Static value for checking

    Imgproc.grabCut(img, firstMask, rect, bgModel, fgModel, 1, 0 /* GC_INIT_WITH_RECT */);
```

PS: This is my first question so sorry if there are any mistakes in formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my point of view, assertion happens when grabcut rect isn't inside mat.
What is the image dimensions ?

Comment: GrabCut rect is well inside matt; that is why I manually entered values; see above code.

Comment: Then img.cols < 318 + 513 and img.rows < 100 + 349 ?

Comment: Sorry what are you asking ?

Comment: Make sure your image is equal or bigger than 831x449 .I see no other way to resolve your problem.