# OpenCv assertion failed

Tags: c++, image, opencv, face-detection, roi

I am working on application for finding face in 2D image and later inside same image I want to find mouth, but I have some problem right now. This is my code so far:

```
for (int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++)
{
        Point pt1(faces[i].x, faces[i].y);
        Point pt2((faces[i].x + faces[i].height), (faces[i].y + faces[i].width));
        rectangle(frame, pt1, pt2, Scalar(255,0 , 0), 2, 8, 0);

                    //I WANT ROI(FOR MOUTH DETECTION) TO BE ONLY HALF OF THE RECTANGLE WITH FACE
        Rect mouthROI;
        mouthROI.x = (faces[i].x);
        mouthROI.y = faces[i].y*(1.5);
        mouthROI.width = (faces[i].x + faces[i].height);
        mouthROI.height = (faces[i].y + faces[i].width);

                    //I CHECK IF NEW RECTANGLE IS EXACTLY BOTTOM HALF OF PREVIOUS ONE
        Point ptAA(mouthROI.x, mouthROI.y);
        Point ptBB(mouthROI.width, mouthROI.height);
        rectangle(frame, ptBB, ptAA, Scalar(0,0 , 255), 2, 2, 0);


        Mat image_roi = frame(mouthROI);

        cvtColor(frame, frame_gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        equalizeHist( frame_gray, frame_gray );

                    // DETECTING MOUTH INSIDE ROI OF EARLIER DETECTED FACE
        mouth_cascade.detectMultiScale(image_roi, mouths, 1.1, 2, 0, Size(30, 30));

        for(int i = 0; i < mouths.size(); i++)
        {
            Point pt1(mouths[i].x, mouths[i].y); // Display detected faces on main window - live stream from camera
            Point pt2((mouths[i].x + mouths[i].height), (mouths[i].y + mouths[i].width));
            rectangle(frame, pt1, pt2, Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2, 8, 0);
        }

}
```

Unfortunately this code does not work. I get error like this:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x + roi.width <= m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.rows) in cv::Mat::Mat(const cv::Mat&, const cv::Rect&), file C:/build/2_4_PackSlave-win32-vc11-shared/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 323
```

How can I fix this error. Thank You all for help!

Comment: The parameters you pass to the function throwing the assert are incorrect. Use a debugger to figure out which function is throwing the assert and back trace it to the line in your code that initiates the call.

Comment: Error is in this place `Mat image_roi = frame(mouthROI);` , but I still don't know why...

Comment: Check out [Similar link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20855192/assertion-error-in-grabcut) and see if you did not commit same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you have initialized `mouthROI` is incorrect. It should be like this instead,

```
<previous code>
mouthROI.width = (faces[i].height);
mouthROI.height = (faces[i].width);

Point ptAA(mouthROI.x, mouthROI.y);
Point ptBB(mouthROI.x+mouthROI.width, mouthROI.y+mouthROI.height);
```

Remember that cv::Rect doesn't take the **position** of the rectangle, it takes the position of the upper left corner and the **width** and the **height**.. Refer to the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#rect) for further details.

HTH