# OpenCV Assertion failed with ROI

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to get every circle in a new window, however I get this error;
[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qxd0t.jpg)

I don't know why that happends. The Rect object gives normal values:
[rect values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBwGs.png)

Code:

```
void scanCircle(int x, int y, int h, Mat src, int rad) {
try {
    Rect region = Rect(x, y, x + h, y + h);
    Mat roi = src(region).clone();
}
catch (...) {
    cout << "Error";
}
```

}

With Google I found this one: [OpenCv assertion failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21248611/opencv-assertion-failed)

However I don't see whats wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means that your rectangle `region` goes out of the bounds of the image `src`.

In fact you're constructing the rectangle with wrong values, it should be:

```
Rect region(x, y, h, h);
```

since 3rd and 4th arguments are width and height, not the coordinates of the bottom right point.

Or you can use the constructor that accepts top-left and bottom-right points:

```
Rect region(Point(x,y), Point(x+h, y+h));
```

Comment: When you draw a rectangle ( rectangle(src, Point(x, y), Point(x + h, y + h), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 1, 8); )

Comment: Yes, that's the same as using constructor: `Rect region(Point(x,y), Point(x+h, y+h));`. You can also draw like: `rectangle(src, Rect(x,y,h,h), ...`